# Docusign - X-HTTP-Method-Override from POST to PUT - in view of updating envelope status to void

Tags: docusignapi, zoho

I am using Zoho Creator and have managed to set an integration with Docusign to create envelopes. However I have a problem to update the envelope status to void, using Docusing REST API method.

Zoho creator offers 2 possibilities: the posturl method and geturl, as follows
`response = postUrl(url, jsonstring, header, false);`

There is no option for the method "PUT" and have tried using the option "X-HTTP-Method-Override": "PUT" in my header (instead of POST) without success.

I keep getting the the following error:

> " INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER\" - "The request contained at least one invalid parameter. Invalid value for 'status' in envelope definition.  Only 'sent' or 'created' (default) are allowed."

Because it's trying to create a new envelope instead of updating.

```
header = map();
headerdetails = map();
headerdetails.put("Username", "xxxxxxx");
headerdetails.put("Password", "xxxxxxxxx");
headerdetails.put("IntegratorKey", "xxxxxxxxxx");
header.put("X-DocuSign-Authentication", headerdetails);
header.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
header.put("Accept", "application/json");
header.put("X-HTTP-Method-Override", "PUT");
url = ("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/xxxxx/envelopes/53f88f09-cc98-43a9-99ce-8769c05a3739");
mapvoid = map();
mapvoid.put("status", "voided");
mapvoid.put("voidedReason", "The report is to be amended.");
response = postUrl(url, mapvoid.toString(), header, false);
```

Thanks in advance for your advice,

Claire

Comment: I'd guess Docusign would have to support `X-HTTP-Method-Override` before this would work. You'll probably either have to ask them to add this for you, or [chase Zoho to implement PUT](https://help.zoho.com/portal/community/topic/http-put-delete-for-constant-contact-api-integration), or maybe use the paid extension they name in that thread if you can't find anything else.

Comment: @Rup The header information copied & pasted from Docusign Rest API explorer suggests that X-HTTP-Method-Override is supported (this is copy/paste below).  

HTTP/1.1
access-control-allow-credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
access-control-allow-origin: *
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
Date: Mon, 05 Feb 2018 18
x-frame-options: Deny
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive

Comment: That's the response headers from Docusign? (You can edit that into the question if you want.) So I guess Docusign should support X-HTTP-Method-Override, then it looks like either Zoho isn't sending the header for you, or Docusign is ignoring it :-/ Can you find out if the header is being sent, i.e. where to look next?

Comment: @Rup this is the response header from Docusign (on the API explorer platform). I have used X-HTTP-Method-Override with Zoho on other integration with other Zoho services and it works fine. Not sure if header is being sent when making the call from Zoho creator though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST API does not support `X-HTTP-Method-Override`, it seems as a bug in RESTAPI Explorer. I have reported RESTAPI Explorer bug to our Dev team, and might fix in future release. You need to use `PUT` to update the status of the envelope.